# SpriteKit. Why .strokeTexture does not work for SKShapeNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, textures, stroke, skshapenode

I can't understand why the "strokeTexture" option isn't working on a SKShapeNode. Or, how can I do border with texture? Thanks in advance!

```
let shape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)
shape.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 400)
shape.fillColor = SKColor.white
shape.fillTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "test")
shape.lineWidth = 50
shape.strokeColor = SKColor.white
shape.strokeTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "test(5)")
```

Output:

[image]

Test image: 
[image]

Test(5) image:
[image]

Comment: You need to give more info man, nobody can read your mind. What is the texture, what is the stroke texture, what is the expected result

Comment: The texture can be seen in the screenshot, it fills the circle. I expect at least some of the reaction (filling, repetition). I tried different textures, textures color and sizes. The result is always the same - black stroke.

Comment: Well from what I am seeing, it is working fine, otherwise your stroke would be white

Comment: I expected to see its texture (stripes) instead of black. Even if I use a different texture (multi-colored) - will be black stroke.

Comment: I do not even see your stroke size on here

Comment: I edited the question, noting this.

Comment: If you rename the texture so it's not got brackets in the name (), does it work?

Comment: I've tried. I'm seeing the exact same problem. Texture is always drawn as black outline.

Comment: Another interesting "bug", when rotating an SKShapeNode with a texture fill, the texture doesn't rotate with the shape. It remains in its original orientation.

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem with the rotation and helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576317/spritekit-stop-rotate-texture-with-cameranode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work in Simulator!

Try it on your device.

I get the feeling this stroke might be being done with metal, whereas the fill is somehow not being done with metal, so is visible in the simulator.

The fill also doesn't rotate with the object on the device, but the stroke/outline and its texture do.

This would tend to indicate that an SKShapeNode without a fill might have reasonable performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Set the width and height of the texture, that is used to render the stroke, multiple of 8 pixels. In your case Test(5) has dimensions 100x100. If you change this texture for another one with dimensions, e.g. 96x96 pixels, the stroke will be rendered correctly and displayed. I don't know, why there are no reference to this fact in the official documentation.